# Multiindex fill columns

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a dataframe X filled with data, where the column names denote currencies:

[image]

And an empty dataframe Y with a multi-index. The first level is the country, and the second level is the currency:

[image]

How can I fill Y with the corresponding data in X, i.e.
place the USD column from X to the (US,USD) column in Y etc?

I did try:

```
for column in rates.columns: 
df2.loc[:, (slice(None), [column])]  = rates[column]
```

Which returns

> ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

I think it is because we have four EUR columns on Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, let's try using `pd.DataFrame.align`:

```
df.align(df2, axis=None, level=1)[0]
```

Output:

```
              US  CA  AU   UK  IT  CH  FR  SP  NL  SW    JP  HK  KO  TW
             USD CAD AUD  GBP EUR CHF EUR EUR EUR SEK   JPY HKD KRW TWD
1969-12-13  8.01 NaN NaN  8.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  6.25 NaN NaN NaN
1970-01-01  8.01 NaN NaN  8.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  6.25 NaN NaN NaN
1970-01-02  7.92 NaN NaN  8.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  6.25 NaN NaN NaN
1970-01-05  7.91 NaN NaN  8.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  6.25 NaN NaN NaN
1970-01-06   NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   NaN NaN NaN NaN
```